# How to move cache folder to to the external drive in OS X 10.9?

Tags: macos, mac, cache

I want to move cache folder for opera, safari and some other apps to the external drive.
I heard that it is possible with symbolic links but also I heard that symbolic links don't work in OS X 10.9 and moving this folders is forbidden in OS X 10.9.
Any way to change cache location for some apps?
In oder not to spoil SSD with temp  files.

Answer (score 0):

Symlinking works just fine in any OS X version, as it's a fundamental UNIX feature.

If you have a symlink rather than the original Caches folder, it could be replaced by a new Caches folder upon login or upon the opening of some Apps.

There is a way to automate replacing it back by a symlink to the Caches folder you have externally, and this way you will get the most out of your Caches as you never lose them.

You can move `~/Library/Caches` folder to the desired destination, let's call it `dest`, then, on Iterm:

```bash
ln -s ~/dest/Caches ~/Library
```

This creates the symlink. Try now to logout, login back, open a browser in order to generate some Caches, then, check if `~/Library/Caches` is still a symlink or there's a Caches folder instead. If it's a symlink, you're done, if you find a folder, I have something you could do whenever the Caches symlink is replaced with a new folder.

Open Iterm, and edit the configuration file of your shell, it's usually `~/.bashrc` or `~/.zshrc`, depending on whether your shell is Bash or Zsh, add this line:

```bash
[ -d ~/Library/Caches ] && rm -Rf ~/Library/Caches; [ ! -L ~/Library/Caches ] && ln -s ~/goinfre/Caches ~/Library/
```

Then reopen Iterm or open a new Iterm window, if no browser or other app that uses Caches is open, then you have the symlink in place making use of your big Caches folder from the external drive. If you get some errors, you will need just to close those apps and open a new Iterm window, if no error messages then close it.

From now on you will have to open Iterm upon every login and close it if you wish before opening some of your favourite apps.

If you have any other folder that contains some app's caches you could add for it a similar line in your config file replacing `~/Library/Caches` with its path, after moving and symlinking.

Note:
SSD is the best place for caches regarding its high read/write speed which is massively needed by those caches to come in, putting them in an HDD may impact the overall performance! Symlinking folders containing some large files or many documents would be better if you wish to preserve some storage or consider having an SSD external storage at least.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1196776)

Comment: I wish the asker gives more info, does he really need to preserve SSD space by getting rid of Caches inside it or what's the point really?
My reply is important as I think that basically, the solution is to do nothing, cause the thing he wants will bring a huge problem, as I understand that the external drive will not be an SSD.